# Can i make my iPad stop autocapitalizing the word "i"?

Tags: ios, spellcheck, autocorrect

If you look at my profile, you can see that i ask people not to capitalize the word "i" in the middle of a sentence. Now, ignoring whether or not this is a good idea, can i make my iPad not autocorrect a lowercase `i` to a capital one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that by writing "i" enough times, the iPad eventually caught on and lets me write the way i want to. I just have to tap the `"i"` in the keyboard suggestions for a few times, and it seemed to add it to the dictionary.

In fact, while writing this post, i accidentally hit <kbd>j</kbd> instead of <kbd>i</kbd> and it autocorrected to "i" for me.

Answer (score 0):

There's not a fix I know of, but there's a workaround.

Prefs > General > Keyboards > Shortcuts.

Hit the + & add
Phrase i
Shortcut ii

It won't accept anything less than a 2-character shortcut, but I'm sure it will take no time at all to remember to type ii for i.

*[now to stop mine doing it... grrr]*